# Hide % of image's width

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

I have two images, each are of five stars side by side, but one is yellow while the other is blue. Something like the below (grabbed from Google):

[image: Stars]

I want to overlap the images on top of each other, and "hide" part of the top image depending on a user's review score of a product.

For example: say the images are 50x10px. I overlap them such that the yellow is on top of the blue. A review comes in 5/5; the image is unchanged. A review comes in 4/5; display only the first 40px of the yellow star image, leaving the remaining 10px to display the blue star (so it'll appear as 4 yellow, 1 blue star in the same image). I can just hide part of the yellow image to get a full range 0/5 to 5/5 using only two images.

How can this be accomplished using HTML, CSS, PHP, and/or JS?

Comment: Have you tried putting the overlaying an image inside of a `<div>` container with `overflow: hidden` and controlling the width of the container?

Comment: Have you considered doing this with an icon font instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use just use a background image and set the width. (I just used your image, but a better image would make it easier)

```css
.rating { 
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDqPE.png); 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.one-star {
    width: 115px;  
}
.one-half-star {
    width: 150px;  
}
.two-star {
    width: 190px;  
}
.two-half-star {
    width: 225px;  
}
.three-star {
    width: 265px;  
}
.three-half-star {
    width: 304px;  
}
.four-star {
    width: 340px;  
}
.four-half-star {
    width: 378px;  
}
.five-star {
    width: 414px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="rating one-star"></div>
<div class="rating one-half-star"></div>

<div class="rating two-star"></div>
<div class="rating two-half-star"></div>

<div class="rating three-star"></div>
<div class="rating three-half-star"></div>

<div class="rating four-star"></div>
<div class="rating four-half-star"></div>

<div class="rating five-star"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a method such that I can pass a variable to an HTML property? I'd rather not have 10 or more CSS classes for each score, but alter the image dynamically.

Comment: You can just set the percentage width if the image is a standard size.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can crop your `img` with **[CSS Clip Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)** as:

```
.Yellow4Stars {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,40px,10px,0px);
}

.Yellow3Stars {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,30px,10px,0px);
}
```

Assuming the width of the full 5 stars is `50px` and the height is `10px`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.under
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
.over
{
position:absolute;
left:40px;
top:10px;
z-index:-1;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="http://path-to-image" width="184" height="46" class="under" />
<img src="http://path-to-image" width="184" height="46" class="over" />

</body>
```

adjust the css for proper positioning.